# Why `msvc_x86` toolset in Visual Studio CMake Settings passes `-A x64` to CMake instead of `-A Win32`?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, x86

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 to build a project using CMake.
It builds successfully for x86_64 architecture.

However, when I did the following:

- Added CMake configuration `x86-Release` , from `CMake Settings`
- Selected `Release` in Configuration Type
- Left `msvc_x86` selected as a Toolset
- Selected `Visual Studio 17 2022 Win64`
- Ran from the menu: Project -> Configure Cache

I got the configuration done for `x86_64` instead of `x86`:

```
Command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" /c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64  -DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES:STRING="Release" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="F:\Work\conan\crono_pci_windows\tools\out\install\x86-Release"  "F:\Work\conan\crono_pci_windows\tools" 2>&1"1>
```

While I expected the command line to have **-A Win32** instead.

Any idea how to set it to build for x86 (-A Win32)?

Thanks,

Bassem

Comment: _"Visual Studio 17 2022 Win64"_ — what is this? Win64 is an old way to specify the amd64 architecture for the MSVS 2017- generators. `cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A Win32` should do what you need.

Comment: Right, but I don't have control over the command line generated from Visual Studio, and when I pass `-A Win32` in the settings, cmake generates an error of using `-A x64` forced by visual  studio, and mine. So, I need a setting in Visual Studio

Comment: I've never worked with CMakeSettings so I can't help with it but you are better off switching to the [CMake presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) as they are [the way to go](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cmake-presets-integration-in-visual-studio-and-visual-studio-code/).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, it's by selecting a 32-bit `CMake generator:` from the list of available generators, e.g. `Visual Studio 17 2022` instead of `Visual Studio 17 2022 Win64`.

Selecting `x86-Release` doesn't seem to be enough.